# Need a better way for "role based authentication middleware" on express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, role-base-authorization

What I have done:

`router.get('/apps', authController.authenticateUser, appController.getApps);`

`router.get('/roles', authController.authenticateAdmin, roleController.getRoles);`

What I want do:

`router.get('/apps', authController.authenticate('USER'), appController.getApps);`

`router.get('/roles', authController.authenticate('ADMIN'), roleController.getRoles);`

When I'm passing parameters like this way getting this error ==>
Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Thank You.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, For better understanding of your problem you also need to post your implementation, what and how you have tried to solve your issue...

Comment: @RohitAmbre Got it thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All express middlewares should return a function that accepts three parameters (request, response, next). In your case, your middleware is registered as an object.  Instead, return an anonymous function(closure) from the `authenticate()` method and resister it as express middleware.

**AuthController:**

```
module.exports.authenticate = function (role) {
   return function(req, res, next) {
      //add your authentication logic here based on the role
   }
}
```

**Router**

```
router.get('/apps', authController.authenticate('USER'), appController.getApps);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, got it the problem was I was using async on the parent function and router requires a callback function not a promise.